# How can i send messurments in cumulocity via mqtt

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I am pretty new to Cumulocity and I am trying to get data into the platform from my own device using MQTT and the smartrest templates. I can get data using the static templates but they only support certain data types. I am struggling to create the appropriate smartrest template in the UI and the documentation doesn't go into much detail.
I am still not able to send measurements in cumulocity UI, I have registered a template on cumulocity and I have published data on this topic, s/uc/template_1500_24_03 and trying to send measurements on it like 1500,,61 but not able to get on measurement  correct me where I am going wrong before I was using a static template in that I was able to send measurement but only numeric data and I need to send a JSON

and have registered a template on cumulicity only need to send measurement

This is what I am trying to do,

This is the topic I published to - s/ut/Custom_1
This is the template body - 10,1500,POST,MEASUREMENT,Type_cov,Cov_Value.value,NUMBER
Now I want to send measurement like this - 1500,67 (here 1500 is template ID and 67 is the value)
However, I do not have any idea as to which topic should I send this data on.

Comment: Try learning first, eg. https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/cumulocity

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different points in your question. I try to address them all, however as you didn't share anything from what you did in the UI I cannot help there.

- Measurements in Cumulocity IoT are always numerical (of course the overall structure is a JSON but the actual measurement values are numerical). I recommend the following documentation for more details https://cumulocity.com/guides/concepts/domain-model/#measurements
- Also the SmartREST static templates generate the standard JSON structures of Cumulocity IoT. The proper JSON is generated by Cumulocity IoT automatically.
- The custom template you shared will not generate measurement JSON structures that will be recognized by Cumulocity IoT applications. You will need a JSON structure like this:

> {   "source": {
> "id": "251982"   },   "time": "2020-03-19T12:03:27.845Z",   "type": "c8y_TemperatureMeasurement",   "c8y_Steam": {
> "Temperature": {
> "unit": "C",
> "value": 100
> }   } }

Note that the JSONPath in that example would be c8y_Steam.Temperature.value (3 levels). Your JSONPath contained only two levels (Cov_Value.value). You need the 3 levels otherwise the measurement will not show up in the UI. You can create other JSON structures but they are then only available directly on the API.

- If you create a template collection via s/ut/Custom_1 then you can publish on s/uc/Custom_1 and subscribe on s/ud/Custom_1 in order to use the templates in that collection
- You can check here for the correct structure how to create templates via MQTT: https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/smartrest-two/#request-templates. The one you shared seems not to be correct

Comment: thanks for reply it will really helpfull i have to send this kind of data on meassurment {"pointId":"622211b0d57f142bec0b8e7e","data":120} and in eventsalarms some complex json so, is it possible to send through static templates or need custom template for that and if custom template needed then after register custom template what process i have to follow for sending messurment or json on cumulocity please hep me with some example or document